# ¿Como guardar la dirección de memoria de un puntero en una cadena en lenguaje C?

Tags: c, string, punteros, memoria

busco guardar la dirección de memoria de un puntero en una cadena, para después compararla con otra cadena que el usuario introduzca, no buco realizar ninguna acción con la dirección de memoria como aritmética de punteros, solo quisiera guardarla como texto simple, pero ya he estado investigando y no me doy una idea de como, espero que me puedan dar algunas ideas, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

- Para imprimir un puntero: [`printf( "%p", ptr );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)
- Para imprimir en una cadena: [`sprintf( destino, "%p", ptr );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)
- Para saber el tamaño necesario del *destino*: [`snprintf( NULL, 0, "%p", ptr );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) (añadir 1 byte para el `\0` del final de la cadena).

Todo junto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *ptr2string( const void *ptr ) {
    int size = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%p", ptr );
    char *result = calloc( size + 1, 1 );
    sprintf( result, "%p", ptr );

    return result;
}
```

Pequeña prueba:

```
int main( void ) {
    char *addr = ptr2string( ptr2string );

    printf( "%s\n", addr );

    return 0;
}
```

> 0x401156

Comment: Ahora sí estamos en paz. Tenía la misma respuesta escrita e iba a darle a "publicar" cuando apareció la tuya :-)

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho, no sé como no se me ocurrió usar sprintf jaja, ya quedo mi programa, graciass trauma.